# Yii2 require all Controller and Action to login

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In my sitecontroller I write like this

```
    'access' => [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'actions' => ['logout', 'index' ,'call-back'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

so If I go to index or call-back action,I'll redirected to login page.
but I have to do it for all action to each controller.
Could you tell me the best way to do it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Place this rule in the beginning of the `rules` section:

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

Omitting the `actions` means all actions.

So your `AccessControl` config will be like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],

                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Keep in mind that rules are applied in order they are declared.

To do it globally without inheritance, add the `as beforeRequest` array below (not inside!) the `components` declaration in your application config:

```
'components' => [ ... ],
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },
],
```

This code will run before each request and block all actions except `login` for guests.

Make sure that there is no `login` action in other controllers than `SiteController`. If there are (and for example they are for different purposes), block them explicitly in according controllers. But it's pretty rare case.

Comment: @arogachev It gives me error: User::identityClass must be set :(

Comment: @pooria Set it in your application config under `components/user` array section like so (example for advanced application): `'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',`

Comment: @arogachev Another problem occurred! I'm using dektrium YII2 user. by this way, it's showing the yii2's default login page instead of dektrium's.

Comment: @pooria Just correct route in redirect method in this case.

Comment: @arogachev I did as you said. It works fine. but it applies even to _'forgot'_ or _'register'_ actions! As said above, I'm using **Dektrium User**. I added _'forgot'_ to first actions array, but again not working.

Comment: @pooria you can define custom rule in dektrium/user/controllers/RecoveryController as per this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31407890/4512651

Comment: @Choxx Thank you, At last I found the problem, I had missed the true name of the action, in the url it shows 'user/forgot' but in real it is 'user/recovery/request' so I just had to look at the yii's debugger :)

Comment: @arogachev is it possible that specific controller can be access by guest (without login) and rules should be declare in "'as beforeRequest'"?

Comment: @arogachev could you point to the documentation where this syntax is described, i.e., adding 'as beforeRequest' in the application configuration array?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add access control to all your controller actions. Please add below code in main config file under components section.

```
'as access' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),//AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'actions' => ['logout', 'index'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: This is incorrect. **1)** This code needs to be added not under `components` section but right in `$config` (at the level above) otherwise it won't work at all. **2)** This part `'actions' => ['logout', 'index']` will additionally allow only `logout` and `index` actions to authenticated users, you need to remove it to allow access for the entire site. Then you can customize access further in `AccessControl` or actions of specific controllers. I also explained it in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41583420/4323648).

Comment: Thanks arogachev. May be my statement confuses you. I mean under components section means where components section end. I didn't mean to add that part of code inside components section.

Answer (score 4):

If you omit the "`actions`"-part from the array completely, it will be valid for all the actions of the controller.

If you want to do it for every controller, just add a layer in between:

```
class MyAccessController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function behaviors() 
    {
         return [
            'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                   'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                   'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                   'allow' => true,
                   'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
             ],
         ];
     }       
 }
```

And then derive your `controller` from that class.
Or you can put it in a `trait` and use add it with a `use` in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in following file.

```
frontend/config/main.php


components =>[ your stuff ],
'as beforeRequest' => 
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
                'rules' =>  [
                                [
                                     'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                                     'allow' => true,
                                ],
                                [
                                    'allow' => true,
                                    'roles' => ['@'],
                                ],
                            ],
            ],
```