# How to allow guest access to some actions in Yii2 Controller?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'd like to know how to configure my controller to allow some actions to be executed as a guest and be able to show the view for that guest in Yii2.

I've tried this rule in my behaviour

```
       'access' => [
           'class' => AccessControl::className(),                           
                'rules' => [
                    [                   
                        'actions' => ['create','update'],       
                        'allow' => true,
                        'ips' => ['127.0.0.1'],                         
                    ]                       
                ],                  
            ]
```

Edit:
This is the config I tried :

```
    'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),                          
                'rules' => [                                
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['create', 'update'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],                  
            ]
```

Edit2: After checking out a new project(yii2-advanced) from scratch and trying to generate the controllers and models again the previous rules worked, I think it was some configuration from the previous project that were preventing me to access as a guest somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your rules

```
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
```

Then the actions `login` and `signup` will be allowed for anonymous users.

Or you can use the `only` method also, to exempt the action which does not require `acl`.

For more details,see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: It still redirect me to the login page :/

Comment: Which action you want to perform? Show me the code.

Comment: i generated a controller using gii and i want to show a view to guest users.

Comment: so what is your action rendering that view? copy that action name and put the same into `actions` array and set the `role` to `?`. That will do it.

Comment: I want to show the views generated by gii, I tried to add  'actions' =>  ['create', 'update']  with the 'roles' => ['?'] in my rule and still get redirected to the login screen, do i need to set something in another config?

Comment: Can you please put the current code in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83218/discussion-between-dency-g-b-and-jeffom).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
 public $freeAccessActions = ['contact-us', 'free-access-action-2'];
```

this will allow the guest to access the

Comment: your last line is cut in mid-sentence