# YII2 How to allow debug/default/toolbar in accesscontrol

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have the following configuration in the web.php file to force users to login first before using the app.

```
'as access' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(), //AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'actions' => ['logout', 'index'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],

        ],
    ],
```

However I get a `Forbidden (#403)` error in the `http://localhost/yii2/debug/default/toolbar?tag=58759099581f2`

How to allow in that in the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this config is incorrect. This part:

```
[
    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

will additionally allow only `logout` and `index` actions to authenticated users. It needs to be changed to:

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

to allow access to the entire site. Then you can customize access further in `AccessControl` or actions of specific controllers. So debug is not the only forbidden page in your case.

I think it was copy pasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333761/4323648) to related question here on SO.

And by the way debug is already enabled in application config in basic app:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    // Below Gii is enabled too, code is omitted for brevity
}
```

So when user is authenticated, you will have access to debug module without any problems.

> **Note:** With this configuration `login` and `error` actions of **every** controller are allowed to non-authenticated users. Be careful with that. There is a chance of actions with similar names exist in other controllers.

**Update:** Actually you can go further and make this solution more flexible with [$matchCallback](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$matchCallback-detail):

```
'as access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                $allowedControllers = [
                    'debug/default',
                ];
                $allowedActions = [
                    'site/login',
                    'site/error',
                ];
                $isAllowedController = in_array($action->controller->uniqueId, $allowedControllers);
                $isAllowedAction = in_array($action->uniqueId, $allowedActions);

                return $isAllowedController || $isAllowedAction;
            },
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

- Place fully allowed controllers in `$allowedControllers` list (prefix it with module name if it's inside a module) to allow them completetely (allow all actions).
- Place allowed actions in `$allowedActions` list (prefix it with controller name and with module name if it belongs to a module).

That way you can have full access to debug module on local server on every page (including `login` and `error`) which can be useful.

Also this prevents from action names coincidence from different modules / controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the toolbar action web.php config file:

```
  'rules' => [

        [

            'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'toolbar'],

            'allow' => true,

        ],
```