# Yii2 all controllers and actions require login, need to add some exceptions. How can I do it?

Tags: yii2, access-control, rules

I've found a lot of answers on how to create Access Control that requires login to all controllers and actions.

The following post shows how I did all controllers require login:

[Yii2 require all Controller and Action to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067849/yii2-require-all-controller-and-action-to-login)

I've used the code below under my components:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ]
],
```

But, I want to add some exceptions to it. Some controllers need to have some actions visible to Guest.

I've tried to use this code inside my behaviors on ReportsController:

```
'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),                          
            'rules' => [                                
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['share'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
            ],                  
        ]
```

Still get redirected to login.

I'm trying to to make actionShare($param) {} public to guests.

What am I missing?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: so you have `'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },` just below your components config?

Comment: Yes, I have the denyCallback defined like that.

Answer (score 0):

First execute

> yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations

from command prompt to create RBAC table in data base.

Then create RbacController in component folder

```
namespace app\components;

use yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
class RbacController extends Controller
{

public function RbacRule($modules = false)
{
    $rules = false;
    if ($modules){
        $rules = [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    $module         = Yii::$app->controller->module->id; 
                    $action         = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
                    $controller     = Yii::$app->controller->id;
                    $route          = "/$module/$controller/$action";
                    $post           = Yii::$app->request->post();
                    if (\Yii::$app->user->can($route)) {
                         return true;
                    }
                }
            ];
    }else{
        $rules = [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    //$module         = Yii::$app->controller->module->id; 
                    $action         = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
                    $controller     = Yii::$app->controller->id;
                    $route          = "/$controller/$action";
                    $post           = Yii::$app->request->post();
                    if (\Yii::$app->user->can($route)) {
                         return true;
                    }
                }
            ];
    }

    return $rules;
   // return true;
}

}
```

then extend to your controller using this RbacController instead of controller.

```
 use app\components\RbacController;

 class AdminController extends RbacController
 {   
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                // [
                //     'actions' => ['login', 'logout'],
                //     'allow' => true,
                //     'roles' => ['?'],
                // ],
                parent::RbacRule(),
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
                'bulk-delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
.......
}
```

> If your controller is inside Modules folder then you have to use 
>   parent::RbacRule(TRUE) instead of  parent::RbacRule(),