# Yii2 advanced : how to set filter for login user in backend?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

All users can now login in frontend and backend side

how can i set limit and filter for login in backend?!

this is my `main-local.php` in backend

```
    'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        'enableUnconfirmedLogin' => true,
        'confirmWithin' => 21600,
        'cost' => 12,
        'controllerMap' => [
            'admin' => 'backend\controllers\user\AdminController',
            'profile' => 'backend\controllers\user\ProfileController',
            'recovery' => 'backend\controllers\user\RecoveryController',
            'registration' => 'backend\controllers\user\RegistrationController',
            'security' => 'backend\controllers\user\SecurityController',
            'settings' => 'backend\controllers\user\SettingsController',
        ],
        'admins' => ['admin']
    ],

]
```

I want only the admin to be able to enter the backend side

Comment: if you are using the advanced template with the RBAC you won't have to do anything, the normal user won't be able to login to the backend. as the `backend` and `frontend` session cookies are separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rbac and set a admin role, then in the controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        //if actions not set, it applies to all actions.
                        //'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        //the 'admin' is your RBAC auth item.
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

More about RBAC see the [RBAC doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac).

You can also set your controller filter simply by ip address adding

```
     //'192.168.*' matches all IP addresses in the segment '192.168.'. If this option is empty or not set, it means this rule applies to all IP addresses.
    'ips'=> ['192.168.*'],
```

And finally, if you want to set a global access control filter, just check the link
[To do it globally without inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30068147/5482799).

Comment: this wont dis-allow the login but instead gives `403` if you access that particular controller