# Yii2 as beforeRequest leading to infinite recursion

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I'm trying to follow this advice about [setting all controllers to require login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067849/yii2-require-all-controller-and-action-to-login), so my config\web.php `$config` definition includes

```
    'components' => [...],
    'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function() {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect('[site/login]');
    },
],
```

But when I run it, Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly".

In the Yii Server command window, I can see what's happening. The first few lines look like this:

> [Sat Nov 16 09:17:53 2019] ::1:51836 [302]: /
>
> [Sat Nov 16 09:17:53 2019] ::1:51837 [302]: /[site/login]
>
> [Sat Nov 16 09:17:53 2019] ::1:51840 [302]: /[site/[site/login]
>
> [Sat Nov 16 09:17:53 2019] ::1:51841 [302]: /[site/[site/[site/login]
>
> [Sat Nov 16 09:17:53 2019] ::1:51842 [302]: /[site/[site/[site/[site/login]

This goes on for 20 times until the browser apparently puts a stop to it.

I *think* what must be happening is that the deny callback calls the site controller, which causes the beforeRequest to be executed again, which calls the deny callback again, and so on, "infinitely". But I don't know what I did wrong and how to stop it. I removed all the access behavior lines from the site controller; perhaps I need to put something back in there to stop it?

Comment: whats with `Yii::$app->response->redirect('[site/login]');` the quotes `'` are incorrect they should be like `Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);`

Comment: Oops! Yes, thank you.

Now I'm getting some other errors, but maybe I can work those out on my own.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The other errors I mentioned were from something I had put in later, but when I took that back out, this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it is in the line

```
'denyCallback' => function() {
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect('[site/login]');
},
```

wrong quotes in `redirect('[site/login]');`, it should be `redirect(['site/login']);`